# How can I show different Menu on Different page?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am using Asta Wordpress theme and its single page website with 4 menus. Now I have created 2 more pages but menu isn't working since it belong to homepage only. Is there any way I can set different menu for different pages?

Comment: Yes you can use, Create custom template and put the custom header

Comment: Using wp_nav_menu() funcntion you can also full fill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```html
usually all the pages follow page.php, have a look if you have header imported in page.php, if you want a different header menu, create a different header and rename as header-pages.php, assign a different menu here as 

<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location' => 'page_menu',
                    'container' => false,
                    'depth'           => 3
                    )) 
                  ?>  

add this to your functions.php by editing the existing array

register_nav_menus( array(
        -------remove this, add the below code only in existing array------
        'page_menu' => esc_html__( 'Page Menu', 'website' )
        -------remove this, add the above code only in existing array------
  
    ));
```

Comment: Is there any easy way out of this. I am not a coder and cant edit codes risking website functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, No sir, You must have to hire a developer then!